# More efficient way of maintaining row order field in database?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB (think MySQL) database where rows have a `position` field. This position can change, but must always be sequential, and start at 1.

Simplified table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `ordered_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

So for example, the user may want the row of ID 10 to move to position #1. This will of course require a reorder of all subsequent items, otherwise there will be duplication in the `position` field. I can't figure out a way to do this in less than 4 queries.

My current solution is below, and it's very straightforward, but I can't help but feel there's a far more elegant way of performing the reorder. In this example I'm moving row with ID32, by user 20, to position 3.

1. Get the `currentPosition` by `SELECT position FROM ordered_data WHERE id = 32`.
2. Fill the gap we're about to make with `UPDATE ordered_data SET position = position - 1 WHERE position > currentPosition AND owner = 20`.
3. Make space for the row's new position (3) with `UPDATE ordered_data SET position = position + 1 WHERE position >= 3 AND owner = 20`.
4. Update the row's position to fit in the gap `UPDATE ordered_data SET position = 3 WHERE id = 32`.

All suggestions very welcome. Combining the first 2 statements with a subselect made MySQL complain about using the same table for update and select.

There are unlikely to be more than 10 rows per owner.

Comment: With 10 rows per group I wouldn't care about performance and use the simplest (most readable) solution. And you already have that. I would just change the order to 1,3,4,2 - This way it would also work with a unique key on `(owner, position)`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Having a bit of trouble getting the reorder working (straight swap leaves gaps, and it's tricky to get my head around the positions), but good idea re: enforcing it at the DB level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the order of your steps isn't as simple as I thought. But with one more step you can make your algorithm work with a unique key on `(owner, position)`. To avoid a duplicate-entry-error at step 2, you can temporarily assign `possition = 0` to the item that you want to move. The full algorithm would look like this:

```
set @owner = 20;
set @id = 32;
set @new_pos = 3;

-- 1. get current position
set @old_pos = (select position from ordered_data where id = @id);

-- 1.1 "remove" the item from its old position
update ordered_data set position = 0 where id = @id;

-- 2. close the gap at the old position
update ordered_data
set position = position - 1
where position owner = @owner
  and position > @old_pos
order by position asc -- important for unique key

-- 3. make space at the new position
update ordered_data
set position = position + 1
where position owner = @owner
  and position >= @new_pos
order by position desc -- important for unique key

-- 4. set new position
update ordered_data set position = @new_pos where id = @id;
```

This method is (IMHO) fine for small groups. For bigger data sets the steps 3. and 4. can be optimized and done in one step. Look at the following example: You have a group of one million items and you want to move an item from position 7 to position 3. After "removing" the item from its position we would update positions 8 to 1000000 and decrement them by 1 to close the gap. Then we would update postions 3 to 999999 and increment them to make space. This would update almost the entire group twice, while all we need is to increment positions 3 to 6. To achieve this, steps 2 and 3 can be replaced with

```
if (@new_pos < @old_pos)
    update ordered_data
    set position = position + 1
    where position owner = @owner
      and position between @new_pos and @old_pos
    order by position desc
else if (@new_pos > @old_pos)
    update ordered_data
    set position = position - 1
    where position owner = @owner
      and position between @old_pos and @new_pos
    order by position asc
else
    -- do nothing
```

Note: This is pseudo code. You need to choose the correct query at application site.

You can even combine them to a single query:

```
    update ordered_data
    set position = position + sign(@new_pos - @old_pos)
    where position owner = @owner
      and position between @new_pos and @old_pos
    order by position * sign(@new_pos - @old_pos) desc
```

But in this case the engine will probably not be able to use an index for the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Hey, this is done via PDO (PHP MySQL), which means more complex queries aren't as easy to implement (although of course possible via stored procedures etc). The first approach (temporarily setting the ID to 0) would work, but I'd be a little concerned about the (very small) chance of a unique conflict if multiple reorders happen. Tyvm for the second part though, will keep hold of that in case the data grows larger than expected. V helpful!